# FrameLayout onClick event doesn't work

Tags: java, android, layout

Have this layout in my app

```
<FrameLayout
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:id="@+id/avatar_layout">
                    <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"

                            android:background="@drawable/knotable_icon"
                            android:clickable="true"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/char_text_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/character"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                </FrameLayout>
```

Its actually profile picture of the user.
I need to implement onClick listener for this FrameLayout.

Behind the scene I have `AvatarListAdapter.java` with

```
public class AvatarListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AvatarUiItem> {
...
private class ViewHolder {
private View.OnClickListener mAvatarClickListener;
}
 private View.OnClickListener mAvatarClickListener;
holder.avatarView=(FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar_layout); //inflates FrameLayout here
holder.avatarView.setTag(itemInfo);
                holder.avatarView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.d("tag", "here we are");

                        if (mAvatarClickListener != null) {
                            mAvatarClickListener.onClick(view);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

then in the main activity :

```
mAdp = new AvatarListAdapter(this, mAvatarUiItemArray, mApp,
                mImageLoader, mDisplayMetrics, mPartCounterNum);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdp);

        mAdp.setOnAvatarClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object object = v.getTag();
                if (object instanceof KnoteUiItem) {
                    KnoteUiItem uiItem = (KnoteUiItem) object;

                 Log.d("tag","avatar click");
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem here is that OnClick event NEVER FIRES.
Really would appreciate  some help on this.

Comment: FrameLayout is parent layout of your ListView Item then why are you not implement ListView Item Click Listener instead FrameLayout Click Listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OnItemClickListener

```
holder.setTag(itemInfo); // Set the tag on the root view rather than the avatarView
.
.
.
.
    OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  Object object = v.getTag();
                    if (object instanceof KnoteUiItem) {
                        KnoteUiItem uiItem = (KnoteUiItem) object;

                     Log.d("tag","avatar click");
                    }
                }
            };

     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```